# SQL Query returning the wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For a college assignment, we have to write a bunch of SQL queries based on question we got, the last question states:

> `Write a query that will indicate which employee has been booked off for the most
> number of days by doctor ‘D0001’. Display the employee name and surname,
> doctor name, and the number of days

My issue is even when I say what value I want to select it return the wrong name of the doctor which I can't understand as to why that happens. The other values in the query are being displayed as it should, the only issue is the Doctor's name from their ID that is incorrectly displayed

The Table

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTORS(
    DOCTOR_ID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DOCTOR_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Values We had to add

```
INSERT INTO DOCTORS (DOCTOR_ID, DOCTOR_NAME) VALUES ('D0001', 'Thabo Ntlali')
INSERT INTO DOCTORS (DOCTOR_ID, DOCTOR_NAME) VALUES ('D0002', 'Deon Coetzee')
INSERT INTO DOCTORS (DOCTOR_ID, DOCTOR_NAME) VALUES ('D0003', 'Kwezi Mbete')
INSERT INTO DOCTORS (DOCTOR_ID, DOCTOR_NAME) VALUES ('D0004', 'Trevor January')
INSERT INTO DOCTORS (DOCTOR_ID, DOCTOR_NAME) VALUES ('D0005', 'Julia Robin')
```

The query I wrote

```
SELECT TOP(1) emp.EMPLOYEE_NAME, emp.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME, d.DOCTOR_NAME, MAX(e.NUMBER_OF_DAYS) AS "NUMBER_OF_DAYS"
FROM DOCTORS AS D, EMPLOYEES emp 
JOIN EMPLOYEE_SICKLEAVE e
ON emp.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE e.DOCTOR_ID = 'D0001' 
GROUP BY emp.EMPLOYEE_NAME, emp.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME, d.DOCTOR_NAME
ORDER BY emp.EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMP.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME
```

Comment: Also specify the expected result. And add a tag for the dbms you're using. (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: TOP 1, but no ORDER BY?!?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh oops forgot to add that line my bad#

Comment: You need to join DOCTORS to EMPLOYEES?

FROM
  DOCTORS AS D
  INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES emp ON D.DOCTOR_ID = e.DOCTOR_ID
  INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_SICKLEAVE e ON emp.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really important point in the comments

> Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

~ [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh)

So let's take your joins:

```sql
...
FROM DOCTORS AS D, EMPLOYEES emp 
JOIN EMPLOYEE_SICKLEAVE e
ON emp.EMPLOYEE_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID
...
```

This is hiding the fact that there are 3 tables, but only one `ON` clause!

This is likely the cause of your problem.

So let's re-write them [as much as we can]:

```sql
...
FROM   DOCTORS
 INNER
  JOIN EMPLOYEES
    ON EMPLOYEES.<SOMETHING> = DOCTORS.<SOMETHING>
 INNER
  JOIN EMPLOYEE_SICKLEAVE
    ON EMPLOYEE_SICKLEAVE.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID
...
```

Comment: This is definitely the right answer in principle. Looking at the where clause, I think the correct join might be to the DOCTOR_ID of the EMPLOYEE_SICKLEAVE table.

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem in addition to the one corrected by the user gvee.
To obtain the employee with the most number of days, you have to order by the sum of days for each employee: `ORDER BY SUM(e.NUMBER_OF_DAYS) DESC`
Also in the SELECT you have to change MAX() in SUM().

Comment: MAX() AND SUM() both give me the same result, will it make a difference which I use

Comment: If you have only one sick leave per employee, SUM and MAX return the same value. If one employee have two or more sick leaves, SUM returns the total number of days, MAX the higher value of days.

Comment: You can choose the one it seems more appropriate, but you have to change the ORDER BY otherwise it will always return the first employee in alphabetical order.